# Getting an object from a recursive deletion Java

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I have a Binary Search Tree that contains nodes. Each node contains a key value and data value, and the nodes are sorted by key. I am trying to write a method to remove an object from my BST provided a key. Here is the code:

```
public Object remove(Comparable theKey) {
        return remove(theKey, rootPtr).data;
    }

public Node remove(Comparable theKey, Node node) {
    Object o;
    if(node == null)
        return node;

    if(theKey.compareTo(node.key) < 0) {
        // go to left subtree
        node.leftChild = remove(theKey, node.leftChild);
    }else if(theKey.compareTo(node.key) > 0) {
        //go to the right subtree
        node.rightChild = remove(theKey, node.rightChild);
    }else if(theKey.compareTo(node.key) == 0) {

        if(node.leftChild != null && node.rightChild != null){
            Node foundNode = findMin(node.rightChild);
            node.key = foundNode.key;
            node.data = foundNode.data;
            node.rightChild = remove(node.key, node.rightChild);
        }else{
            if(node.leftChild != null){
                node = node.leftChild;
            }else{
                node = node.rightChild;
            }
        }
    }
    numNodes--;
    return node;

 }
```

I would like to return the data value associated with the DELETED node. The issue I have is that: in the public Object remove() method, wouldn't the returned value always be the data value of the root node? I believe this would occur because the final returned call from the second method would be a reference to the rootPtr (root pointer). If this is the case, how can I save the data from the deleted node?

Comment: I think you'd be much better restructuring this. It would be much cleaner and easier to understand if the algorithm wasn't recursive. You can just iteratively search for the right key in the tree, store the value, remove the node and replace with its left or right child, and then return the value you stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution seems to be to add an output parameter than hands back the result:

```
public Object remove(Comparable theKey) {
  Object[] result = new Object[1];
  rootPtr = remove(theKey, rootPtr, result);   // fix for deletion from a one-node tree
  return result[0];
}

public Node remove(Comparable theKey, Node node, Object[] result) {
  if(node == null) {
    return node;
  }
  int diff = theKey.compareTo(node.key);
  if (diff < 0) {
    node.leftChild = remove(theKey, node.leftChild, result);
  } else if (diff > 0) {
    node.rightChild = remove(theKey, node.rightChild, result);
  } else {
    result[0] = node.key;
    if (node.rightChild == null) {
      node = node.leftChild;
    } else if (node.leftChild == null) {
      node = node.rightChild;
    } else {
      Node foundNode = findMin(node.rightChild);
      node.key = foundNode.key;
      node.data = foundNode.data;
      node.rightChild = remove(node.key, node.rightChild, new Object[1]);
    }
    numNodes--;
  }
  return node;
}
```

Returning the found node doesn't work without significant changes because the return parameter is used to replace nodes as needed, and in the case where the found node has two children, you'd need to make a copy or insert a new node. Handling the case where the root node gets removed would be an issue, too.

p.s. I am assuming this is not a "trick question" and you can't just return theKey -- which has to equal the found key after all :)

Comment: If I wanted to return the key, then I wouldn't be able to return the node and hence my deletion code wouldn't be able to properly restructure the tree, correct?

Comment: Yes. You could return both in some for of container, but that would probably be more object creation and management overhead

Answer (score 0):

You have to return the value, that you are receiving from the recursive remove-call.

p.ex:

```
if(theKey.compareTo(node.key) < 0) {
    // go to left subtree
    return remove(theKey, node.leftChild);
}else if ...
```

Now you will run throught the tree, until you find the correct node and that node will be given to the node which is the parent of the node to remove, and the parent will than give it to his parent and so on, until the root will return the node to his caller.

Comment: That won't work (at least without changing the code significantly), as the return value is used to update the tree (push up child nodes to replace the removed node as needed).